# Expectation of a function of multiple non-identical independent exponentially distributed random variables

Tags: probability, expected-value

I'm currently writing a set of notes on coalescent theory and I'm writing an example on how to directly calculate the probability of a given rooted genealogical tree. This is done by writing an expression for the probability in terms of the waiting time and then solving that. We have that

$T_n \sim $ Exp$\left(\binom{n}{2}\right)$

And the expression I need to take the expectation of is

$\frac{\theta^4}{2^4}\left(e^{-\theta\frac{2T_4 + 3T_3 + 2T_2}{2}}\left(T_3T_2(T_4+T_3)(T_4+T_3+T_2)\right) \right)$

Where $\theta$ is some constant representing the mutation rate.

I'm totally lost on how to calculate this directly. A solution or resources on how to do this myself would be very much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: @Amir,
Hi, I'm not totally certain what you mean. In an example I saw which skipped this final step there was no bounding or estimation as far as I know, it was directly computed.

Comment: You can use the method suggested in an answer below. You need to use the mgf of exponential distribution, and its $k$th derivatives (@LetacGérard).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T$ is exponential with mean $m$ then $X=T/m$ is exponential with mean 1. Therefore your complicated exponential can be written $e^{aX_1+bX_2+cX_3}$ and its expectation is $\frac{1}{(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)}. $ You are interested in the expectation of the product of this exponential by a complicated polynomial, therefore enough is  to compute  for suitable integers $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$

$$E(e^{aX_1+bX_2+cX_3}X_1^{\alpha}X_2^{\beta}X_3^{\gamma})$$$$=(\frac{d}{da})^{\alpha}\frac{1}{1-a}\times (\frac{d}{db})^{\beta}\frac{1}{1-b}\times (\frac{d}{dc})^{\gamma}\frac{1}{1-c}$$$$=\frac{\alpha!}{(1-a)^{\alpha+1}}\times \frac{(\beta!}{(1-b)^{\beta+1}}\times \frac{\gamma!}{(1-c)^{\gamma+1}}$$

Comment: Hi there, this is very helpful. Would suitable $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ be any that are present in the polynomial that I can partially differentiate the polynomial in order to achieve? Thank you.

Comment: Of course since your polynomial is $$T_2^2T_3^2+T_2^2T_3T_4+T_2T_3^3+2T_2T_3^2T_4+T_2T_3T_4^2$$ you have to apply to $$(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=(2,2,0), \ (2,1,1),\ (1,3,0)),\ (1,2,1),\  (1,1,2).$$